# Accessing SSIS Variables in Data Flow task

Tags: c#, ssis, dataflowtask

In an SSIS script task, and of the SSIS variables can be accessed using the following syntax:

Dts.Variables["VariableName"].Value

However, in a data flow task the syntax changes a bit to this:

Variables.VariableName

At the same time, certain variables do not appear to be available in the Data Flow task. Even though they are clearly listed in the Variables toolbox, and they are accessible in a Script Task, they do not come through for some reason. Can someone explain to me why this is and how to syntax/method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to answer this question myself (quickly). When opening the Script task, under custom properties the ReadOnly/ReadWrite Variable list is available. Select the variables you want to use in their respective categories and use the appropriate syntax above.